# How to use Latex scientific notation in Moodle?

Tags: latex, moodle

How to use Latex scientific notation in Moodle ?

Several professional styles are available that make documents look “like
printed”. Changing style requires changing one single line in the document,
with consistency ensured.
• High-quality maths typesetting
• Only a few commands to define the structure of text,
no knowledge of typography or book design required.
• Complex scientific documents can be created automatically:
– bibliography
– index
– cross-references
– table of contents, lists of figures, tables etc.
– . . .

Answer (score 0):

Moodle has a built in TeX filter, so Latex is automatically converted

First it needs to be enabled via

Site admin > Plugins > Filters > Manage filters > TeX notation = on

Then enter Latext delimited with `$$` eg:

```
  $$ \sqrt{x + y} $$
```

Will display

[image]

Note : Moodle has a built in binary library for converting Latex, but you should install the full Latex libraries on your server if possible

see https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/TeX_notation_filter